# Send props and convert image to svg using vue-svg-inline-loader in Vue

Tags: vue.js, svg

I using [vue-svg-inline-loader](https://github.com/oliverfindl/vue-svg-inline-loader)

In first component I send using props source to image svg:

```
<IconComponent :imgIcon="'../../assets/img/icon-example.svg'" />
```

Next I have second component when I get props:

```
<img svg-inline :src="imgIcon" alt="icon">

export default {
   name: 'IconComponent',
   props: {
      imgIcon: {
         type: String,
         required: true
      }
   }
};
```

But library `vue-svg-inline-loader` can't conver img to svg.

I have:

[image]

When in second component I change to:

```
<img svg-inline src="../../assets/img/icon-example.svg" alt="icon">
```

then image convert correctly to svg.

***EDIT:***

I added:

```
<object :data="require(`@/assets/img/${this.name}.svg`)" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

and image convert to svg, I have this structure in DOM.

[image]
And now I need change color using SASS. I write code:

```
.icon {
   margin: 0 map-get($margins, m1);
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   height: 100%;

   object svg g g {
      fill: red;
   }
}
```

But not change color to red.

Answer (score 0):

According to this issue, it's not possible to have vue bindings like `:src`, when using this library: https://github.com/oliverfindl/vue-svg-inline-loader/issues/2

This [comment](https://github.com/oliverfindl/vue-svg-inline-loader/issues/2#issuecomment-539064474) suggests to use this library instead: https://vue-svg-loader.js.org/

**EDIT**

In my humble opinion, a library that does not support VueJS bindings, is not useful. Can you switch to other library. This one seems promising: https://github.com/seiyable/vue-simple-svg

Comment: Yes, I saw this repository. But I don't know how I can send props. In this repo images svg are get by `import ... from ...`

Comment: In your code can you try `:src="require(imgIcon)"` and check if it works?

Comment: Added edit to my answer. I suggested another library.